# CheckBox Binding with Viewmodel property and IConverter not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple `CheckBox` and I want to bind a value from my `ViewModel` to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`. The value derived from `ViewModel` is of type sbyte.
I have included a small converter class for that.
However, this code is not working.
Please suggest the right way of doing this.

#### XAML

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:TrueFalseConverter x:Key="TFC"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkOutOfSales" DataContext="{Binding DCIM}"  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentRec.Out_of_Sales, Converter={StaticResource TFC},Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code Begind converter:

```
public class TrueFalseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return ((bool)value == true) ? 1 : 0;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return ((sbyte)value == 1) ? true : false;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working ? 
Is there any System.Windows.Data Error: 40 messages in output window?

Comment: By the way... Your converter looks wrong... You have to change the Convert and ConvertBack... In Convert you have to return boolean, and in Convertback return sbyte

Comment: Yes,This is what the error says
BindingExpression path error: 'Out_of_Sales' property not found on 'object' ''DM_ItemGroup' (HashCode=40786534)'. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentRec.Out_of_Sales; DataItem='DC_ItemGroup' (HashCode=55957829); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name='chkOutOfSales'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')

DM_ItemGroup is my model and DC_ItemGroup is my ViewModel.
CurrentRec is the currently selected record from the ObservableCollection<DM_ItemGroup> in my ViewModel,ie DC_ItemGroup

Comment: In my ViewModel,ie DC_ItemGroup,i had this property named as "Out_of_Sales" while in my DataModel,it was "Out_Of_Sales" ...This was the culprit..:-).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...I had mistyped Out_Of_Sales as Out_of_Sales in my viewmodel...that was the issue...:-).
Thanks for your time..